# how to separate the json_encode value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i get the json data from the php  to ajax how can i separate the value of the console data just like that

i have to set in my id only the agent name not the hole `"name" : "Testing"`

**This is my console value**

```
[{"agent_module_id":"1","agent_module_number":"101","name":"Testing","description":";;;","agent_mobile":"0123456789","email":"d@gmial.com","category":"","unit_price":null,"cost_price":null,"deleted":"0"}]
```

**This is My PHP Code**

```
 $this->load->model("member");
            $agent_value = $_POST['agent_value']; 
            $data["results"] = $this->member->get_agent_data($agent_value);
            echo json_encode($data["results"]);
```

**This is my JavaScript Code**

```
  function agentForm()
{
    var agent_id = document.getElementById("agent_code").value;
        if(agent_id !='')
        {
            document.getElementById("agent_operation_form").style.display ="block";

        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url("members/get_agent_data");?>',
        data: { 'agent_value': agent_id},
        type: "post",
      /*  success: function(data){
             // document.write(data); //just do not use document.write
             var fd_values = data.split(/,/);
             document.getElementById("agent_name").value=fd_values[2]; // unique _id
            document.getElementById("agent_mobile_number").value=fd_values[1];

            console.log(data);*/
            success: function(data){
             // document.write(data); //just do not use document.write
             var fd_values = $.parseJSON(data);
             document.getElementById("agent_name").value = fd_values[0].name; // unique _id
            document.getElementById("agent_mobile_number").value = fd_values[0].agent_module_number;

            console.log(fd_values);
        }
        }
      });
        }else
        {
        document.getElementById("agent_operation_form").style.display ="none";
        }

}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: You can use json parse in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as (Not Tested). You can parse your JSON data using `$.parseJSON`

```
success: function(data){
             // document.write(data); //just do not use document.write
             var fd_values = $.parseJSON(data);
             document.getElementById("agent_name").value = fd_values[0].name; // unique _id
            document.getElementById("agent_mobile_number").value = fd_values[0].agent_module_number;

            console.log(fd_values);
        }
```

Comment: @Uchila  please check the below the edits code... i have error in again

Comment: Remove one brace after `console.log(fd_values);`

Comment: You've added extra brace after your `console.log(fd_values); } ` `<-------` remove this one and it'll work

Comment: very very thanx a lot